# How to turn off pressure sensitivity for grease pencil with a tablet?

Tags: customization, grease-pencil

How to turn off pressure sensitivity for grease pencil with a tablet?

Comment: If no answer shows up try requesting this via http://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-funboard   try to be descriptive so it's clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

For Wacom tablets (I don't know about others) you can set pressure sensitivity at OS level using the control panel (not blender's user preferences). You can customize the behaviour for different applications, so you can have blender have specific settings to your particular needs.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In case you have a grease pencil drawing and want to normalize it (remove the pressure effect ) :

- copy and paste in the text editor
- click Run_Script ( all grease pencil drawings will have the same thickness )

---

```
import bpy

new_pressure = 1.0  # you can change this for different thickness  (always <1 ) 

for Gpencil in bpy.data.grease_pencil :
    for layer in Gpencil.layers:
        for frame in layer.frames:
            for stroke in frame.strokes:
                for p in stroke.points:
                    p.pressure = new_pressure
```

---

example :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to draw with pressure then manually normalize the stokes' width.

The feeling of pressure on strokes is created through increasing or decreasing its vertices *size* (as strokes are actually vectors/curves).

So, the same way you "Shrink/Fatten" curves' control points/vertices/nodes, you can do it with GP strokes.

1. In the 3D View Editor, open the Toolshelf <kbd>T</kbd>, then select the
   Grease Pencil Tab; push the *Enable Editing* button;
2. Under *Edit Strokes*, push the *Select All* button;
3. With the mouse cursor/pointer over the viewport, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
4. If you move your mouse it will scale the vertices. You can also press a numeric value. I suggest: press 0 (zero), then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> again and press some other numeric value (like 100) - this way all vertices will have the same size.